# Problem with vim macros. Limitation to letters In the alphabet

Tags: macro

Hello I like vim but their seems to be a limited macro system from what I understand. The documentation I have
says to specify a letter to define the macro. Does this mean that I a restricted to the letters In the alphabet
for macros?

Comment: can you give an example?  the macro name must be from a-z but the contents are unrestricted by alphabet

Comment: Also, mappings are less restricted in name if you need more

Answer (score 3):

That's correct, macro names are limited to a-z.   Macros are stored in the named registers a-z, so a macro might be overwritten if you yank to a register a-z that currently holds a macro.

If you are hitting the limits of what can easily done by a macro, then other options are:

- custom mappings (`:help :map`)
- calling custom Vimscript functions (`:help :function`)
- new commands (`:help :command`)

My experience is that writing a function offers much more flexibility and power than a macro.   Once your function is nice, then you can define a mapping or command to call the function.